# How to Show Countdown Timer on Camera in flutter

Tags: flutter

how to implement countdown on camera in flutter ?
I'm using stack, camera and text. but it's not working .

[image]

Comment: can you add the code, which you have tried so far.

Comment: // for open Camera//_openCamera() async {
    try {
      final photo = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (photo == null) return;
      final tempImage = File(photo.path);
      print(tempImage);
      
    } catch (error) {
      debugPrint(error.toString());
    }
  }  // i'm using stack but it's not working//Stack(
      children: [
        _openCamera(),
        Center(
          child: Text(
            'Timer',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );